Given a speaker set at fixed volume, do sound files (with different loudness) affect the power used by the speaker?
I understand that the volume set on a speaker will impact the amount of power used, but does the sound data itself also affect the amount of power used?
For example, suppose I record a sound file where I'm screaming into the microphone and another sound file where I whisper into the microphone.  If I play those two sound files through the same device, would the sound file where I screamed into the microphone consume more power than the sound file where I whispered? My intuition is yes, but someone I spoke to implied that boosting microphone gain on the recording side can lead to louder playback sound without requiring more power on the playback side.

Is this a question that's more appropriate for electronics.stackexchange

The answer is as usual that it depends.
Stronger sounds takes more power to the speaker. But it depends a bit on the frequencies as well. Bass tones takes more power that descant tones.
Most power amplifiers will draw more power from the outlet when they put out more power to the speakers. Really efficient power amplifiers of class D outputs more than 90% of the input power to the speakers.
Some circuit configurations that can be used in power amplifiers however draw about the same regardless. Examples are some more "pricey" class A power amplifiers where most of the input power is turned into heat. (As always this discussion is a simplification).
